# Filter two lists of dictionary by 2 value pairs AND group them together

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, filter

I have 2 lists of dictionaries , let's say :

```
List_D1 = [{'Symbol':'GFX','Time':'9:36am', 'Change':-0.18, 'Volume':181800},
            {'Symbol':'AIG','Time':'9:36am', 'Change':-0.15, 'Volume': 195500},
            {'Symbol':'AXP','Time':'9:36am', 'Change':-0.46, 'Volume': 935000},
            ]
List_D2 = [{'Symbol':'AA','Time':'7:36am', 'Change':-0.08, 'Volume':181800},
            {'Symbol':'AIG','Time':'9:36am', 'Change':0.99, 'Volume': 197500},
            {'Symbol':'GFX','Time':'9:36am', 'Change':-0.46, 'Volume': 935000},
            ]
```

I want to pick items in separate lists with same 'Symbol' and 'Time' value:
In example above it should pair :

**Pair 1:**

```
List_D1 : {'Symbol':'AIG','Time':'9:36am', 'Change':-0.15, 'Volume': 195500} 
List_D2 : {'Symbol':'AIG','Time':'9:36am', 'Change':0.99, 'Volume': 197500}
```

**Pair 2:**

```
List_D1 :{'Symbol':'GFX','Time':'9:36am', 'Change':-0.18, 'Volume':181800}
List_D2 :{'Symbol':'GFX','Time':'9:36am', 'Change':-0.46, 'Volume': 935000}
```

Now I just go thru each entry in different lists of dictionary , I am wondering is there any better idea to get this done more efficiently ?

I am thinking of using python's **itemgetter** to `sort(List_D1+List_D2)` and then use `groupby` function to pair the whole sorted list and groups item I want to pair together . However , by doing this , **I cannot tell which item is from which lists .**

```
Here is my source code :

from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

ListsBoth = List_D1+List_D2

key1 = 'Symbol' 
key2 = 'Time'
grouper = itemgetter(key1,key2)
ResuListx2.sort(key=grouper)
for key, testItem in groupby(ListsBoth,key=grouper):
        // here I can group all items with same 'Symbol' AND 'Time' value together, but just missed the original "List" info - where each item in same group comes from. but I need it for my application.
    ...... handle each item in testItem ()
```

Comment: Why is it important to know which item came from which list?

Comment: Because there is a "log" file in each entry , sorry I didn't show that in my description. What I need to do is "diff"  those log contents . when diff them I need to know what is the newly generated error/logs . List_D1 is generally the 'original' while List_D2 is the newer generated one.

Comment: Is there guaranteed to be no symbol dups in each list?

Comment: @AChampion I posted what I have tried . In each List_D* , there is no entry has same value of both "Symbol" and "Time" Pair . Meaning , I can locate single entry in one List_D* by search one "Symbol" / "Time" pair –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could transform each list of dicts into a dict with a tuple of the symbol and time as the key and then do a simple lookup across both to create the pairs you are looking for, e.g.:

```
In []:
D1 = {(d['Symbol'], d['Time']): d for d in List_D1}
D2 = {(d['Symbol'], d['Time']): d for d in List_D2}
[(D1.get(k, None), D2.get(k, None)) for k in set(D1) | set(D2)]

Out[]:
[({'Change': -0.18, 'Symbol': 'GFX', 'Time': '9:36am', 'Volume': 181800},
  {'Change': -0.46, 'Symbol': 'GFX', 'Time': '9:36am', 'Volume': 935000}),
 ({'Change': -0.15, 'Symbol': 'AIG', 'Time': '9:36am', 'Volume': 195500},
  {'Change': 0.99, 'Symbol': 'AIG', 'Time': '9:36am', 'Volume': 197500}),
 ({'Change': -0.46, 'Symbol': 'AXP', 'Time': '9:36am', 'Volume': 935000}, None),
 (None, {'Change': -0.08, 'Symbol': 'AA', 'Time': '7:36am', 'Volume': 181800})]
```

You can eliminate any unmatched pairs by changing it to:

```
[(D1[k], D2[k]) for k in D1 if k in D2]
```

Now you can iterate each pair doing what you need to do, e.g.:

```
In []:
results = [(D1[k], D2[k]) for k in D1 if k in D2]
for l1, l2 in results:
    print(l1, l2)

Out[]:
{'Symbol': 'GFX', 'Time': '9:36am', 'Change': -0.18, 'Volume': 181800} {'Symbol': 'GFX', 'Time': '9:36am', 'Change': -0.46, 'Volume': 935000}
{'Symbol': 'AIG', 'Time': '9:36am', 'Change': -0.15, 'Volume': 195500} {'Symbol': 'AIG', 'Time': '9:36am', 'Change': 0.99, 'Volume': 197500}
```

Comment: Thank you @ACampion, the tricks  I learned is : - generated a "new" combo key which is the value I care ; - then  use set(Dict) generated new keys set ONLY .So I can go over each dict and pair data I want together.  Cool !

Answer (score 0):

```
List_D1 = [{'Symbol': 'GFX', 'Time': '9:36am', 'Change': -0.18, 'Volume': 181800},
           {'Symbol': 'AIG', 'Time': '9:36am', 'Change': -0.15, 'Volume': 195500},
           {'Symbol': 'AXP', 'Time': '9:36am', 'Change': -0.46, 'Volume': 935000},
           ]
List_D2 = [{'Symbol': 'AA', 'Time': '7:36am', 'Change': -0.08, 'Volume': 181800},
           {'Symbol': 'AIG', 'Time': '9:36am', 'Change': 0.99, 'Volume': 197500},
           {'Symbol': 'GFX', 'Time': '9:36am', 'Change': -0.46, 'Volume': 935000},
           ]

b = map(lambda x: x.get('Symbol') + '_' + x.get('Time'), List_D1)
c = map(lambda x: x.get('Symbol') + '_' + x.get('Time'), List_D2)
e = map(lambda x: (List_D1[b.index(x)], List_D2[c.index(x)]), set(b) & set(c))
for i in e:
    print(i)
```

Comment: "c.index" seems like it is not valid operation on obj b and c

Comment: @Jia It should be list(b).index(x) and list(c).index(x) in Python3

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `itertools.groupby` and then save only the results with more than one resulting items:

```
import itertools
List_D1 = [{'Symbol':'GFX','Time':'9:36am', 'Change':-0.18, 'Volume':181800},
        {'Symbol':'AIG','Time':'9:36am', 'Change':-0.15, 'Volume': 195500},
        {'Symbol':'AXP','Time':'9:36am', 'Change':-0.46, 'Volume': 935000},
        ]
List_D2 = [{'Symbol':'AA','Time':'7:36am', 'Change':-0.08, 'Volume':181800},
        {'Symbol':'AIG','Time':'9:36am', 'Change':0.99, 'Volume': 197500},
        {'Symbol':'GFX','Time':'9:36am', 'Change':-0.46, 'Volume': 935000},
        ]
d = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(List_D1+List_D2, key=lambda x:(x['Symbol'], x['Time'])), key=lambda x:(x['Symbol'], x['Time']))]
final_data = {a:b for a, b in d if len(b) > 1}
```

Output:

```
{('AIG', '9:36am'): [{'Symbol': 'AIG', 'Time': '9:36am', 'Change': -0.15, 'Volume': 195500}, {'Symbol': 'AIG', 'Time': '9:36am', 'Change': 0.99, 'Volume': 197500}], ('GFX', '9:36am'): [{'Symbol': 'GFX', 'Time': '9:36am', 'Change': -0.18, 'Volume': 181800}, {'Symbol': 'GFX', 'Time': '9:36am', 'Change': -0.46, 'Volume': 935000}]}
```

Comment: it can pair groups I want , but one problem here is , I cannot tell from final_data , which item is from which List_D* , correct ?